# The active class not working properly in different browsers

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser, padding

There is a website
http://sulopa.co.in/kalpproject/en/.

If you scroll down then the navbar will appear. If you are opening it in Google chrome, and clicking each section of navbar, its coming properly with headings. But if you open in Firefox browser, the headings gets clipped off.

Also if you open a section in Google chrome, navbar menus are not getting active.

For ex, if you click the section Amenities, Gallery section remains active. If you click Floorplan, Amenities section remains active.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: yes i am using bootstrap

Comment: Can you make a smaller example that still demonstrates the issue? I mean, I presume you don't really need all that code and all those stylesheets in order to show the issue.

Comment: I have given website an its a small issue. you can chck for youself

Comment: I think @MrLister meant please just use the relevant parts of the code, not the whole website, then put it into something like [JSBin](http://www.jsbin.com) or [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net).

Comment: I am new to html and css, so I dont exactly which css is for which class. Can't you check inspect element and help me? I have given the website

Answer (score 0):

Just change your line 15 of your `main.js` file which is currently,

```
window.location.hash = href;
```

Replace this line with this code,

```
if(history.pushState) {
    history.pushState(null, null, href);
}
else {
    location.hash = href;
}
```

Basically you were facing the page jumping problem on setting the window url hash in firefox. The solution is to simply use the history API supported on modern browsers along with fallback on old ones.